# Enom DNS URL redirect doesn't work - HTTPS redirect does not work

Tags: redirects, https

I am not running a webserver, and I simply want to redirect x.mysite.com to a Calendly link. I did this using the Host records - I set it up so x.mysite.com redirects to Calendly.com/mycalendly. However, this used to work but now is broken.

After some diagnosis, I noticed that if I input x.mysite.com into the web browser manually, the redirect works. and if I click on any link that contains x.mysite.com - it does not work. The underlying issue seems to be when a link is clicked, it assumes its a https link, which the redirect fails whereas if I manually type in the URL, it checks for both HTTP and HTTPS and it will use HTTP URL redirect, which works.

What is the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You more-or-less hit the problem on the head when you said "I am not running a web server".  Redirecting HTTPS requires a webserver along with the bits to handle HTTPS certificate negotiation.

The only way to fix this is to have a web server which handles HTTPS negotiation and then sends the redirect request, or have Calendly add your domain name to their https certificate (the later I expect is unlikely to happen).